# Neo4J - Post pagination for multiple Unions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hello I'm trying to paginate over a Cypher which contains multiple Unions:

```
MATCH(node:D1593731983259)
    WHERE toLower(node.name) CONTAINS {searchTerm}
RETURN node {.*}
UNION
MATCH(node:D1593031169841)
    WHERE toLower(node.name) CONTAINS {searchTerm}
RETURN node {.*}
```

I want to paginate the whole results to limit the number of results that all unions can have something like:

```
MATCH(node:D1593731983259)
    WHERE toLower(node.name) CONTAINS {searchTerm}
RETURN node {.*}
UNION
MATCH(node:D1593031169841)
    WHERE toLower(node.name) CONTAINS {searchTerm}
RETURN node {.*}
skip 20 limit 20 //<------------ like this
```

But that pagination only applies on the last match for `(node:D1593031169841)` and not for the rest of them.

Can anybody help me with a workaround for this issue?

I'm using Neo4J version 3.5.14

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can [migrate/upgrade](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/upgrade/planning/) to neo4j 4.x, you can take advantage of the newly-added support for [post-union processing](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/#subquery-post-union):

```
CALL {
  MATCH(node:D1593731983259)
    WHERE toLower(node.name) CONTAINS $searchTerm
  RETURN node
  UNION
  MATCH(node:D1593031169841)
    WHERE toLower(node.name) CONTAINS $searchTerm
  RETURN node
}
RETURN node
SKIP 20 LIMIT 20
```

Comment: does that will limit the results from the queries inside the CALL? because I've used call.apoc.query using the apoc library but the issue there is that neo4J will first run the queries inside, and then will paginate over the full results, which is then a performance issue for me

Comment: @CarlosHerreraPlata Yes, the limit affects which “sub-queries” will be executed. Try to look at the request profile: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/